# Using Request.QueryString in ASP.NET Embedded Code Block

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, parameters

I am attempting to pass a parameter from one file to another via the URL after a button is clicked. These are written with Express.js (`index.ejs` to `items.ejs`).

As it stands currently I am setting the URL parameter in a defined Javascript function:

```
function loadItems(page, subcategory) {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, "?subcat=" + subcategory) //param set
    $('#mainContent').load(page);
}
```

where `subcategory` is the changing variable.

From there I am trying to read this parameter during an ASP.NET function written in embedded code blocks.

```
<% if(items[i].subcategory === Request.QueryString["subcat"].Value) { %> //get param
    <% if (items[i].status === "Supported") { %>
        <tr class="success">
            <td><a href="/items/edit/<%= items[i]._id%>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</a></td>
            <td id="item name"><%= items[i].name%></td>
            <td id="subcat name"><%= items[i].subcategory%></td>
            <td id="item status"><%= items[i].status%></td>
            <td id="item desc"><%= items[i].description%></td>
        </tr>
```

However I am met with an error which states `Request is not defined` and a callback to the above if statement. It is my understanding that on the ASP.NET side of things, `Request.QueryString` is a part of `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`.

How would I go about including this into my code blocks so that I am able to pull the parameter from the URL? Or, if this is not the way to be looking at this problem, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to use code behind.  Embedded code blocks are an old-school throwback from the asp days.  But if you must, then you should be able to do something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<script run=server>
    Protected Function GetSubcat() As String
      Return Request.QueryString["subcat"].Value
    End Function
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
   Subcat value is <% =GetSubcat()%>.
</form>
```

Comment: Would I be able to implement this if all of the pages that I am using are `.ejs` files, or is that going to be problematic?

Comment: The code won't work unless they are ASP.NET .aspx pages. How would an .ejs file know anything about .NET?

Comment: That's what I thought, sorry I'm very new to web app development so I'll probably ask some (really) dumb questions. Is there a way to call the .aspx pages? The entire app is written in .ejs/.js so far.